# Agora Flutter: Able to see video on local views, but on remote view other speaker see's black screen

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I'm using flutter agora SDk, when trying on two phones, I can see the local video when turned on, but when a remote video is viewing the stream its a black screen for them.
Here's the code for local & remote view display:

```
    class _VideoCallWidgetState extends State<VideoCallWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<VoiceChatCubit, VoiceChatState>(
      buildWhen: (prev, curr) => prev.videoChatEnabledRtcIds != curr.videoChatEnabledRtcIds,
      builder: (context, state) {
        final myRtcUid = context.read<VoiceChatCubit>().myRtcChannelUid;
        // No one's video is enabled
        if (state.videoChatEnabledRtcIds.isEmpty) {
          return Container();
        } else {
          // Single video participant
          if (state.videoChatEnabledRtcIds.length == 1) {
            // Only me as participant
            if (state.videoChatEnabledRtcIds.contains(myRtcUid)) {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  videoMethod(context, RtcLocalView.SurfaceView());
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: 120,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: RtcLocalView.SurfaceView(),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              // Single participant (not me)
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  videoMethod(
                      context,
                      RtcRemoteView.SurfaceView(
                        channelId: state.roomTitle,
                        uid: state.videoChatEnabledRtcIds.first,
                      ));
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: 120,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  child: RtcRemoteView.SurfaceView(
                    channelId: state.roomTitle,
                    uid: state.videoChatEnabledRtcIds.first,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
```

Comment: Are you giving the same channel name everywhere?

Comment: yeah, viewing same everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the if condition that you're using `state.videoChatEnabledRtcIds.contains(myRtcUid)` since this will always will be true even when the remote user joins, so the `else` statement might not trigger.
Also, from the code I am not so sure what `videoMethod` is. Can you please share the code for that as well.